# Listview height

Tags: android, listview

I have listview that loads all audio files from sd card...there is alot of files..but listview looks prety bad..every row height automatically resizes depends of item name that shows in row..background is white and text is grey so it is hard to notice it...I want to set every row height to same so it looks like this [image]

here is my code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/PhoneMusicList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I think you can Use customized list view where you can fix the height of the list item

Answer (score 1):

In your group row.xml 
Instead of  `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` for the listview row height give a fixed height..This will solve your problem......
Something like this
`android:layout_height="50dp"`

Comment: wouldnt that fix the height of the listview itself.. ??

Answer (score 0):

Use the customize list view. Create a layout for one list view item. Set the height in that. Apply adapter in .java file. Then it works fine. I done the same thing and it works for me.